# Is it possible to move the __MigrationHistory System table to a new server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2012

We recently moved our database to a new server. However, at the time, we did not allow the Code First migrations to create the database. We used another tool to migrate the tables and data. The __MigrationHistory table was not moved during this time. The __MigrationHistory is a system table in our original DB.

I cannot seem to find a way to import or export the __MigrationHistory table so we can allow future migrations to take place.

The only other thought we had, is to have the application recreate the database and migrate the copied data to the new version of the DB. The only issue is we have millions of records to move and it is quite a long process.

Comment: Just script the table and data using SSMS... Look for "generate scripts"

Comment: have you seen the docs on [creating your own history context](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Migrations%20History%20Table%20Customization)?

Comment: @BradChristie, no I have not seen that. However, the DB is already created and we just want to move the migration data. This will be helpful for future version of our app.

Comment: @DDiVita: Well then i suggest you see that docs page. ;-)

Comment: @ta.speot.is, I did, but it seems to script it as a non system table and not sure if this will still work with Entity Framework's migration context. Would it know to look for the __MigrationHistory in a non system table?

Comment: @ta.speot.is, also the __MigrationHistory is not listed since it is a system table.

Comment: @DDiVita: If you move to EF6 it's not a system table. And the custom-implemented `HistoryContext` will allow you to map [`HistoryRow`] to the table you see fit (instead of the default, `__MigrationHistory`)

Comment: @BradChristie, we can't move to EF 6 right now, unfortunately. That is a nice feature though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following script to move the EF MigrationHistory table from the system tables to the user tables (of a database tree structure):

```
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[TempMigrationHistory] FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory];

DROP TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory];

EXEC sp_rename 'TempMigrationHistory', '__MigrationHistory';
```

This way I can export the table by choosing standard script/export option under SSMS.

(The complete description of handling this issue is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b182758-ef29-4407-b62b-12aee816aa45/migrationhistory-being-a-systems-table))

Comment: Actually so logical, but did exactly what I wanted! So many years later! Thank you!